# Is try catch in actors always bad practice?

Tags: exception, akka, actor

I know excpetion handling in actors should in general be done with a supervisor strategy. But is this valid for all cases?

**Example**

- There is one actor which is some kind of database.
- There are several source actors which can add data to the database actor.
- The parent child relationships of these actors are unknown.
- To add data to the database actor the source actors must be registrated at the database actor.
- If a not registrated source actors tries to add data to the database an exception is thrown.

If I follow the the error handling strategies of akka actors strictly, a supervising actor would have to handle this case.

I would prefer to catch the exception inside the database actor and send to the source actor a message, that something went wrong. Then the source actor could react (registrate to the database and try again).

Is this a good practice? Or is the total actor setup wrong? If a supervisor strategy is preferred, how should it be implemented?

Comment: why do you need to throw exception in this case? You can just send right answer or publish right event

Comment: The underlying database, which the database actor uses throws an exception. So either catch the exception and send a message or use a supervisor strategy.

Comment: but you claim that you can check whether smb is registered directly in register list which db actor holds. So if not - don't send any request to db and just response with "unauthorized" message etc.

Comment: The database can not but I could store it in the actor itself. But this is not really different from try catch except the syntax. So only usw the supervising actor, when something unexpected happens?

Comment: @hami I agree with you. My rule of thumb goes like this: Catch expected exceptions and handle them if possible. If not possible or the exception is an unexpected one, let the actor crash and let the supervisor handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to catch exceptions and make them into responses when you feel it's appropriate. I'd recommend using Scala's [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try), as in:

```
Try(dangerousOperation()) match {
  case Success(res) => sender() ! res
  case Failure(ex)  => sender() ! UnableToStoreThingy("reasons...", ex)
}
```

Or something like that (you can also `try.failed.map { ex => doThings(ex) }`), depends on your style preference.